# Node - Large for loops with database work running out of memory

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, for-loop, out-of-memory

So I have a large amount of data I need to place into database after I generated it all. Now whether I attempt to do this while the data is being generated or after, doesnt matter. It crashes both ways

I have code like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i<4000, i++){
    for(var z = 0; z<1000; z++){
        c.query("REPLACE INTO `"+i+"`VALUES ("+z+", "+data+",)", function (err){
            if(err){
                throw err;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

After about 100 loops of the outer for loop, it gets killed. When i look at the memory info, its running out of memory.

I can get better results (it makes it to about 1500 of the outerloop) if i change it all to self-calling functions with a delay on the call for about 100ms. I assume that's because the event queue has time to clear out.

I've tried this in every way I know how so far. I've tried redis and now mysql, neither work. It does work with a json file database but not these.

Anyone have any ideas of how I can make this loop through. This is a one time task, so speed is of no concern at all, i just need it to complete lol.

Edit: This is in right direction, but keep gettin Max call stack size exceeded. Can't figure it out.

```
async.eachOfSeries(chunk, function(item, key, outerCallback){
    async.eachOfSeries(item, function(value, slot, innerCallback){
        //console.log(slot);
        c.query("REPLACE INTO `"+key+"` (r, v) VALUES ("+slot+", "+value+")", function(err){
            if(err){
                throw err;
            }
        });
        innerCallback();
    }, function(err){
        outerCallback();
    });
}, function(err){
    callback();
});
```

I tried setting a delay to the callbacks, but no luck.

Comment: Please show logs when it gets killed. Also what is `c`? Which module are you using?

Comment: @Sangharsh there is no error. Just "killed", only reason i know its out of memory is logging the memory info every loop. Its mariadb for node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand so far from the question:

`c.query()` is asynchronous method. 
I would loop using [`async.eachSeries`](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachSeries) (or `async.eachLimit`).

Alternatively you can use Promise or async/await.

**Edit:**

Changed the place where `innerCallback` is called.

```
async.eachOfSeries(chunk, function(item, key, outerCallback){
    async.eachOfSeries(item, function(value, slot, innerCallback){
        //console.log(slot);
        c.query("REPLACE INTO `"+key+"` (r, v) VALUES ("+slot+", "+value+")", function(err){
            if(err){
                throw err;
            }
            innerCallback(); // Add callback here
        });
        // innerCallback(); // Remove this call
    }, function(err){
        outerCallback();
    });
}, function(err){
    callback();
});
```

Comment: This is definitely in the right direction. However, I keep getting "max call stack size exceeded" I cant see what's causing it. Check the main post for an edit :) @Sangharsh

Comment: See "Common Pitfalls --> Synchronous iteration functions" in Async [docs] (http://caolan.github.io/async/)

Comment: Thanks! This ended up working to fix the call size error, however i still run out of memory! At around 500ish iterations of the outer loop, i run out of memory. Shown in this [screenshot](https://gyazo.com/71b5e30f78214b9432b536a92542c379) of me logging the process.memoryUsage. The server is weak, but it should be able to handle this. @sangharsh

Comment: Edit: I didn't see your edit. I ended up using async.ensureAsync around my iteratee function. Which I think was messing it up. When I change it to the way your edit shows, it's working, but its MUCH slower. Ill let you know in 5 ish minutes when it's done if it solves my problems.

Comment: Yes, it will be slower. Here we are waiting for a `query()` to finish before calling another way. In first version of your code, all 4000 * 1000 calls to query were made simultaneously. Try `eachOfLimit` in inner loop, it should give better speed.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. I think this will be my last question: How should i find the right limit? Should i just play around with it ?

Comment: Play around. I generally use in range of 10 to 50 but have no concrete reason behind it.